# Using Putty on a Synology NAS to Load an old HDD and not loose the data

Tags: linux, ntfs, nas, synology, ntfs-3g

I am trying to mount a NTFS drive on my Synology NAS and copy the data to one of the volumes so I can then mount the drive with the Synology storage manager and keep the files...

I am trying this command and it is not loading:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdd2 /volume2/3TBHDD
```

I used was following the thread "Accessing an old, populated hard drive with a NAS?" but I can't get it to work. I had to use Putty to get root access...

I did the `parted /dev/sdd` and print and returned this:

```
model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB         Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   3001GB  3000GB  ntfs Basic data partition   msftdata
```

I looked at the `ntfs-3g` manual but I can't work out what the destination should be...

I made a directory on `Volume2` called `3TBHDD` but I am unsure if this is what I was meant to do.

I get this error message :

```
root@myNas:~# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdd2 /volume2/3tbhdd
mount: mount point /volume2/3tbhdd does not exist
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "_I am trying this command and it is not loading.._" what error do you see? have you checked `dmesg`?

Comment: You are mixing upper case and lower case names in your question. Linux (and your Syno runs on a Linux version) is CASE-SENSITIVE. So you better check how you exactly created the 3TBHDD folder.

Comment: re "_/volume2/3tbhdd does not exist_" - please note that paths are case sensetive... `3TBHDD` is not the same as `3tbhdd`

Comment: so I used spaces in my names.... so it looked more like volume2/"Video and Music"/3TBHDD

Comment: so I used spaces in my names.... so it looked more like                 **mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdd2   /volume2/"Video and Music"/3TBHDD** doesn't seem to work as it lists the mount options  but   **mount -a ntfs-3g /dev/sdd2   /volume2/"Video and Music"/3TBHDD** just returns the command line but I can't see anything mounted in the directory

Comment: This is the error from the -t option : **mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general command you need to mount a hard drive on your system is the following

`mount -t TYPE DEVICE MOUNT-POINT`

Where TYPE is the filesystem type, DEVICE is the device name, and MOUNT-POINT is a directory on your computer.  The MOUNT-POINT is case-sensitive, as discussed above.

Example:

`mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdd2 /volume2/"Video and Music"/3TBHDD`

If you are seeing the error "**unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'**" it may be because you need to install the ntfs-3g software package. On Debian-derived systems, try `apt-get install ntfs-3g`. On Redhat-derived, try `yum install ntfs-3g`. Additionally, you will need a `fuse` (File System in Userspace). Make sure `fuse` is installed in additional to `ntfs-3g`. If you use a GUI software package manager, try to search for these packages and install them.

Lastly, if the software you need cannot be installed, and you only need to **read** from your HDD try:

`mount -t ntfs /dev/sdd2 /volume2/"Video and Music"/3TBHDD`

The ntfs mount type is read-only, and should be built into the kernel.

Comment: Cheers I think this would have worked........... but I pulled the drive put it back into my computer copied the files then put it back in the NAS and added it to the system....